# ffmpeg-php não funciona

Tags: php

Estou tentando gerar uma thumbnail com ffmpeg-php, mas nenhum comando dele funciona, sempre da um erro dizendo que a classe não foi encontrada, exemplo: Fatal error: Class 'ffmpeg_movie' not found.

Usando o comando `if(!extension_loaded("ffmpeg")) exit("Extensão não carregada");`
ele sempre diz que a extensão não foi carregada mas o wamp mostra a extensão, quando vou em PHP>PHP extensions.

Não sei se pode ser problema com as dlls, mas peguei elas nesse site: http://ukphpdeveloper.blogspot.com.br/2012/08/how-to-install-ffmpeg-in-xampp.html

Comment: e no `phpinfo();`?

Comment: Não aparece nada sobre o ffmpeg no phpinfo().

Comment: Então você deve ter instalado mas não habilitado, no WampServer no menu veja se tem o sinal de "check" `✓`, se não estiver clica e então clique em "restart" (no menu mesmo)

Comment: Ele já está como o sinal de "check".

Comment: Toni tenta agora o restart, pode ser algum bug do WampServer

Comment: Tipo ele já ta desde antes de eu fazer a pergunta, eu até já reiniciei o pc.

Comment: Toni em que pasta esta a DLL? E qual o nome completo da DLL?

Comment: C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.31\ext; o nome da dll é "php_ffmpeg.dll".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vá no `php.ini` abra ele com um editor como notepad++ ou SublimeText e procure um local aonde esta escrito:

```
; Windows Extensions
```

E adicione esta linha:

```
extension=php_ffmpeg.dll
```

Se a linha já existir ela deve estar assim:

```
;extension=php_ffmpeg.dll
```

Então tire o ponto e virgula e após reinicie o WampServer

Se ainda não aparecer nada no `phpinfo();` é porque você baixou a versão errada da DLL, você tem que baixar a versão para a **mesma arquitetura** que o PHP foi compilado, se não tiver a dll compativel e você não puder compilar por você mesmo então não será possivel usar esta extensão, todavia existe uma alternativa.

### Alternativa em PHP

Do mesmo criador existe um "port" escrito puramente em PHP https://github.com/char0n/ffmpeg-php, baixe a ultima versão em:

- https://github.com/char0n/ffmpeg-php/releases

Depois instale "o programa" (não estou falando da DLL) `ffmpeg` ou `ffprobe`:

- https://www.ffmpeg.org

Comment: Não teria como simplesmente baixar a versão correta da dll ao invéz de usar esse "port"? Se tiver como poderia falar onde eu baixo ou a versão que eu deveria baixar?

Comment: @Toniotti se no site não tiver a versão pra arquitetura que foi "compilado" não tem como, a não ser que você entenda um pouco de C++ e saiba compilar e então baixe exatamente a versão correta do MSVisualStudio e e baixe o source da DLL e compile você mesmo, então irá funcionar, caso contrário não vai, .dll e .exe são coisas compiladas, e compilação é baseado no tipo do compilador (Mingw, GCC, VS, etc) e arquitetura de processadores (x86, x64, ARM, etc), não é um arquivo qualquer, é "parte de um programa" compilado em "código de máquina", não tem como uma dll diferente funcionar em dois lugares

Comment: Fora que instalar o FFMPEG-PHP em um servidor contratado seria praticamente impossivel, a não ser que a hospedagem faça isso pra ti ou você tenha controle administrativo sobre a tal hospedagem.

Comment: Bom eu não entendo nada de C++ então vou tentar usar esse "port" mesmo, mas obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @Toniotti sim é o jeito, nem é questão de C++, mas sim de como foi compilado, o proprio PHP e o Apache dentro WampServer são "compilados", no seu caso provavelmente foram compilados no MSVC, mas não sei qual versão do MSVC e para arquitetura x64. Se o autor/dono das DLLs não tiver uma DLL compativel com teu PHP/Apache/arquitetura então é impossivel fazer qualquer coisa funcionar. Por isso o port em PHP é mais fácil, pois ele são apenas uma série de scripts em PHP, o que vai facilitar também instalar no servidor.